How to smoothly insert new messages in a reversed ListView in Flutter
I am using a reversed ListView in Flutter to display a chat list. When pulling to insert historical messages at the top, the scrolling remains stable. However, if a new message is added while the list is already scrolled to the bottom, the list automatically scrolls to the new message at the bottom, which prevents me from using animateTo to smoothly transition. How can I insert a new message smoothly without the list auto-scrolling?
